# Fastest bulk insert into javascript arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I wanted to check to see which was faster in adding elements to an array in javascript:

1. Adding a list of 5 per iteration
2. Adding 5 single items with adding position to the subscript
3. Adding one single item pr iteration

I ran it on my Linux Mint 16, Firefox 37.0.2

1 and 2 turned out much better than 3.

When I ran it 1,000,000 times 1 was noticably better than 2.

However when I ran it 10,000,000 the results were reversed. *What would be the explanation for that?*

```
var amount = 1000000;
var iter = 11;
var a = new Array(amount);
var b = new Array(amount);

var results = [];

for (j=1; j<iter; j++) {
    var clock = new Date().getTime();
    for (i=0; i< amount; i+=5) {
        a[i] = [2,2,2,2,2];
    }
    results.push("quintuple primitive insert attempt " + j + " took " + 
                                 eval(new Date().getTime() - clock) + "ms");

    var clock = new Date().getTime();
    for (i=0; i< amount; i+=5) {
        a[i] = 2;
        a[i+1] = 2;
        a[i+2] = 2;
        a[i+3] = 2;
        a[i+4] = 2;
    }
    results.push("single primitive insert with inline inc attempt " + j + 
                     " took " + eval(new Date().getTime() - clock) + "ms");

    var clock = new Date().getTime();
    for (i=0; i< amount; i++) {
        a[i] = 2;
    }
    results.push("single primitive insert with single iterator attempt " + 
                 j + " took " + eval(new Date().getTime() - clock) + "ms");
}
```

The code is demonstrated here:

http://jsfiddle.net/lash/cL3wewj4/

(I also tried using homogenous and heterogenous arrays to insert content, in which 2 always was the best. The attempt is in the same jsfiddle source, commented out)

Comment: There's a very big difference between the end result of 1 vs 2 and 3, doesn't the end result matter to what you're doing?

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, but your first method doesn't behave how you assume it does. What you're doing is adding a new array at each 5th index, so `a[0]` will return an array of five 2s, while `a[1]` up to `a[4]` will return nothing.

Comment: Also: You don't need to use `eval` to do math. And reusing the array between tests makes your timings invalid.

Comment: I think your first method generate different things as 2 and 3. First method is a list of list. As for the performance, method 2 will have less operations since you manually put the 5 items in each iteration, this can be a bit faster. However, method 2 has the limitation that if the total length is not dividable to 5, you have extra items been inserted. In javascript is ok, in Java you get exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're taking times of things that are not the same:

First off, you're taking times of creating a matrix whose elements at position i%5 = 0 contain an array of five elements. The rest of the elements (i%5 != 0) are undefined. This array has a length that depends on amount due to the fact that you're adding to the variable `i` five in each iteration and some elements at the end of the array might not be initialized (directly or indirectly).

```
for (i = 0; i < amount; i += 5) {
    a[i] = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2];
}
```

Secondly, you're creating an array whose elements are all equal to 2.

```
for (i = 0; i < amount; i += 5) {
    a[i] = 2;
    a[i + 1] = 2;
    a[i + 2] = 2;
    a[i + 3] = 2;
    a[i + 4] = 2;
}
```

Thirdly, you're doing the same as two.

```
for (i=0; i< amount; i++) {
    a[i] = 2;
}
```

Since one is different than 2 and 3 the results don't make sense.